# jQuery 2.2.4 and 3.6.0 versions overlapping errors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, overlap

I found this piece of code that I want to integrate to a website (a template that I purchased) which is still under development. The issue is that the website is running on jQuery 3.6.0, and this code that I want to integrate is using jQuery 2.2.4.

Now, when I add the code to the website, it works fine, but in the other hand, other website functions stops running. and when I check the console I see errors like `Object.fireWith` and `Function.ready` and I'm not good with JavaScript.

Can you help me make this piece of code run on the latest jQuery 3.6.0 instead of 2.2.4?

Thank you for any help.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  // Please run it with window.onload, not with document.ready
  initSmoothScrolling('.carouselblocks', 'smoothscroll');
});

function initSmoothScrolling(carouselblocks, carouselanimation) {
  /*
   * @param {String} container Class or ID of the animation container
   * @param {String} animation Name of the animation, e.g. smoothscroll
   */
  var sliderWidth = 0;
  var animationWidth = 0;
  var sliderHeight = $('>div>div:first-of-type', carouselblocks).outerHeight(false);

  $('>div>div', carouselblocks).each(function() {
    animationWidth += $(this).outerWidth(false);
  });

  // detect number of visible slides
  var slidesVisible = $(carouselblocks).width() / $('>div>div:first-of-type', carouselblocks).outerWidth(true);
  slidesVisible = Math.ceil(slidesVisible);

  // count slides to determine animation speed
  var slidesNumber = $('>div>div', carouselblocks).length;
  var speed = slidesNumber * 2;

  // append the tail    
  $('>div>div', carouselblocks).slice(0, slidesVisible).clone().appendTo($('>div', carouselblocks));

  // Detect the slider width with appended tail
  $('>div>div', carouselblocks).each(function() {
    sliderWidth += $(this).outerWidth(false);
  });

  // set slider dimensions
  $('>div', carouselblocks).css({
    'width': sliderWidth,
    'height': sliderHeight
  });

  // Insert styles to html
  $("<style type='text/css'>@keyframes " + carouselanimation + " { 0% { margin-left: 0px; } 100% { margin-left: -" + animationWidth + "px; } } " + $('>div>div:first-of-type', carouselblocks).selector + " { -webkit-animation: " + carouselanimation + " " + speed + "s linear infinite; -moz-animation: " + carouselanimation + " " + speed + "s linear infinite; -ms-animation: " + carouselanimation + " " + speed + "s linear infinite; -o-animation: " + carouselanimation + " " + speed + "s linear infinite; animation: " + carouselanimation + " " + speed + "s linear infinite; }</style>").appendTo("head");

  // restart the animation (e.g. for safari & ie)   
  var cl = $(carouselblocks).attr("class");
  $(carouselblocks).removeClass(cl).animate({
    'nothing': null
  }, 1, function() {
    $(this).addClass(cl);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carouselblocks {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.carouselanimation {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.carouselanimation div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div class="carouselblocks">
    <div class="carouselanimation">
      <div><img src="http://fpoimg.com/200x200?text=First"></div>
      <div><img src="http://fpoimg.com/200x200?text=Second"></div>
      <div><img src="http://fpoimg.com/200x200?text=Third"></div>
      <div><img src="http://fpoimg.com/200x200"></div>
      <div><img src="http://fpoimg.com/200x200"></div>
      <div><img src="http://fpoimg.com/200x200"></div>
      <!-- cut -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- script src="./script.js"></script -->
</body>
```

Comment: Including two versions of jQuery into a single page is a recipe for pain and suffering.

Comment: ... or even multiple copies of the same version